# Template path in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say, I connected the route `/` to WelcomeController's index action.

Inside of the index.html.erb-Template I want to display the path of the template from Rails.root upwards, ie.

```
<h1> We are rendering: <%= how_do_i_do_this? %></h1>
```

to render to

```
<h1> We are rendering: app/views/presentation/index.html.erb</h1>
```

In Rails 2 I could access `template.path`, but this doesn't work anymore

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of how template rendering works in Rails, you will now be able to use __FILE__ for this instead. This works for me:

```
<%= __FILE__.gsub(Rails.root.to_s, "") %>
```

There may be a better way to do this however, but I couldn't find it when I went looking.

Comment: Yep, this does the job. However, it comes with the major drawback that you can't factor it into a helper method, since that would screw up the __FILE__ constant.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan's answer works. If you also want to put your method in a helper, use `Kernel#caller`. Here is a method I'm using to do something similar:

```
def has_page_comment? code = nil
  if code.nil?
    # grab caller file, sanitize
    code = caller.first.split(':').first.gsub(Rails.root.to_s,'').gsub('.html.erb','')
  end
  ...
end
```